# In flag view, could we have easy access to resolution of previous flags?

Tags: feature-request, flags, moderator-tools

If a post is flagged then I, as a moderator, see all the flags it's received, not just the current one, when viewing it from the flag queue.  That's *very* handy for understanding the history of a post.

It would be even *more* handy if I could see the *resolution* of those past flags, either inline or on mouse hover.  If I'm not the moderator who handled it, or if I was but it wasn't recent, I have no idea what the response to a previous (related) flag was unless I click through to the post and then go to the mod tools from there.  Sometimes issues are complicated and I'd like to be able to take advantage of prior work from other mods; I *can* do that now, but I'm asking for the workflow to be a little easier.